# CAML query to get data for SSRS from SharePoint list

Tags: caml-query, caml

I am writing CAML query to get data from sharepoint list

```
 <RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ListName>Test</ListName>
   <ViewFields>
     <FieldRef Name="Document_x0020_Name" />
     <FieldRef Name="Time_x0020_of_x0020_Upload_x005c" />
   </ViewFields>
<Query><Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name="Data"/><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">
'+StartDate+'</Value></Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name="Data"/><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">'+EndDate+'</Value></Lt></And></Where></Query>
</RSSharePointList>
```

However I want one condition to be included in above query.
User should select the range of Time_x0020_of_x0020_Upload\Modification to get above values.
Startdate and EndDate are two Date/Time paarmetrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put your filter condition between the Query tag, for example:

```
<Query><Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name="Data"/><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">'+dateFrom+'</Value></Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name="Data"/><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">'+dateTo+'</Value></Lt></And></Where></Query>
```

Comment: the type of field is string. Can we manipulate the comparison based on this?

Comment: It's better to first convert the String to Date, because if you compare date in string format the "less than" or "greater than" comparison doesn't work correctly

Comment: I have edited my question